# slot of QClipboard::dataChanged() was called twice

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qclipboard

The slot detectClipboardUrl of QClipboard::dataChanged() was called twice sometimes when I copy url in Google Chrome's address bar in this code, tested with PyQt5.7,Python3.5 on Win7 32bit, also on Linux Mint 18,
  while I need the slot to be called only once , is this a bug ? any solutions ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        self.clipboard.dataChanged.connect(self.detectClipboardUrl)  

    @pyqtSlot()
    def detectClipboardUrl(self):
        print(self.clipboard.text())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is it really **only** the Google Chrome address bar that is affected?

Comment: @ekhumoro when copy text from a text edit, no this effect

Comment: So the problem is in Chrome, not Qt.

Answer (score 3):

If the changes are duplicates, you can do something like:

```
class MainWindow(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
    self._cb_last = hash(self.clipboard.text())
    self.clipboard.dataChanged.connect(self.detectClipboardUrl)  

    @pyqtSlot()
    def detectClipboardUrl(self):
        text = self.clipboard.text()
        cb_current = hash(text)
        if cb_current != self._cb_last:
            print('clipboard text changed:', text)
            self._cb_last = cb_current
```

The reason for using `hash` is simply to avoid keeping very large strings in memory.

Alternatively, if the two signals arrive very close together, you could use a `QTimer` to block any changes that occur within a few milliseconds of the first one.

**UPDATE**:

As I suspected, the problem is caused by a bug in Chromium: see [Issue 173691](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173691).

Comment: I guess it is  a bug

Comment: @iMath. Maybe a bug in Chrome, but not in Qt.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to use `hash` like that, as the possibility of a collision is pretty likely. `hash()` is mostly used internally for dicts, where collisions are handled correctly.

Comment: @TheCompiler. Hmm, "pretty likely" seems a rather gross exaggeration. Using `hash` is perfectly fine for a non-critical application like this. There's only likely to be a few hundred checks per session, not the several *billion* you'd need to guarantee a collision. If `hash` really was as vulnerable as you suggest, it wouldn't even be fit for use with `dict`.

Comment: Your answer stopped successively copy the same text,  a even better workaround without  the restriction is here https://gist.github.com/redstoneleo/2ac9ca8037e1621c2f49b264573d03fc